# How to query COMMENT ON COLUMN?

Tags: hana

In HANA-Database there are comments on columns (something like extended properties in SQL Server). 
I can see the values of these comments through HANA studio (in SAP HANA Administrative Console) by double-clicking the table. 
The values are shown in the GUI within the tab "Columns" in a column called "Comment".

Where is the table holding this Information (COMMENT ON COLUMN)?

I tried to query SYS.COLUMNS (as I think this table should hold the information) but my systems tells me: "insufficient privilege: Not authorized". 
There must be another way to get this information with my privileges, as I can see it through HANA Studio.

Comment: `sys.table_columns` also contains that information

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_Name: Thank you very much!

Comment: Please always use the public synonym `TABLE_COLUMNS` instead of the direct view access to `SYS.TABLE_COLUMNS`. The `SYS` schema is not public and may be changed w/o notification.